# cannot use address operator in function declaration c++

Tags: c++, header

It's a code that works on Windows with Visual C++ 10 and I'm trying to port it on Linux:

```
static const wstring format(const wchar_t* format, const va_list& args);
```

This is the error I get:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘va_list’ with no type
> - expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token

Comment: this is not allowed with GNU compiler ? I have used: const va_list args and I get the same error.

Comment: By the way, that ampersand (the `&` character) in the function prototype, is not the address-of operator, it means that you pass the argument *by reference*.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the correct header ([`<cstdarg>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdarg)).

Comment: Thank you Joachim. It works now. Could you say please why this is needed on GNU and with Visual C++ is not ?

Comment: @cristian Maybe the header is included by some other (system) header file?

Comment: Yes, I think was included by other header file having <stdarg>